# Add new column to dataframe value-by-value, given dataframe size is unknown

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe with a column, E, that includes at most the values

```
[200 300 400 600 1000]
```

However as I am reading several sets of data like this from a source, not all my dataframes have these 5 values, i.e. some rows will be missing from one dataframe (e.g. has `[200 300 400 1000]`, while another may have a different set of entries (e.g. `[200 300 600]`). I appreciate that these appear as np.arrays or Series here, but in my application I am dealing with a dataframe containing other columns, which I haven't shown here. I've shown them like this here for simplification.

What I want to do is add fixed values in a second column corresponding to these values if they appear, i.e. if the dataframe contains 200, add in a new column 100. Then, if 300 is in the column, add 100. There are fixed values I need to add that map to the values in the above, so if my dataframe looks like

```
E
200
300
400
600
1000
```

then it should become

```
E       D
200     100
300     100
400     200
600     400
1000    400
```

but if it's e.g.

```
E
200
300
600
```

it should become

```
E       D
200     100
300     100
600     400
```

In effect, the values in E are mapped to fixed values in D, i.e.

```
[100 100 200 400 400]
```

(they are in fact the differences between the value in E and the next value in E, *assuming all values are in E* and none are missing).

Any help or guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: See my answer, happy to assist further if needed

Comment: Thanks too for giving me a chance to answer the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IICU:

```
# Conditions
a=df['E']<=300
c=df['E'].between(500,1100)
b=df['E']==400
df['C']=0#Create Column C and populate zeroes
```

Use nested np.where to apply conditions

```
 df['C']=np.where(a, 200,(np.where(b, df['E']-200, np.where(c,400,df['C']))))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, it works perfectly. It's surprising how useful np.where can be!